# How to solve this error: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 28, 28, 3)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to make my code recognize numbers using tensorflow for my school project. But I keep getting this error. Can someone help me with it? Thank you soo much!

Tried like flatten, changing the size etc but no vail...

Here are my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
import keras
test_image = image.load_img('Number 8.jpg', target_size=(28, 28))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
result = model.predict(test_image)
print(np.argmax(result[0]))
```

Expected to be an array of 3

Answer (score 2):

I think it is coming from this line

`tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),`

You can replace it with

`tf.keras.layers.Flatten()`

Even though your image is (28,28), when training there will be a batch dimension `[batch_size, 28,28]`. Since you do not pass batch size in `model.fit` a default value is used.